# Как разделить масив чисел на подмасивы по три елемента с разным порядком?

Tags: javascript

```
// Есть масив чисел:
const ls = [51, 56, 58, 59, 61]
// Как сделать так чтоб получилось так:
[51,56,58], [51,56,59], [51,56,61], [51,58,59], [51, 58,61], [51,59,61], [56,58,59], [56,58,61], [56,59,61], [58,59,61]
```

Comment: У тебя размер новых массивов будет 3. Значит тебе надо написать цикл обхода основного массива, где ты будешь выбирать 3 случайных индекса. Далее ты формируешь их них массив и записываешь в новую переменную (массив с массивами). После каждой новой генерации тебе надо сравнивать новый массив с имеющимися, например так: `a.join() == b.join()`. Либо, надо пробегаться перебором по идексам, чтобы получить конечность итераций. С другой стороны, всегда можно получить конечность... Насколько я помню 3^5 и есть число вариаций.

Comment: к сожелению ето не рандом

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю, вам нужны комбинации без повторений. Краткая теория: https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/tree/master/src/algorithms/sets/combinations Как минимум две реализации см. в популярных репозиториях с примерами алгоритмов на JS: https://github.com/trekhleb/javascript-algorithms/blob/master/src/algorithms/sets/combinations/combineWithoutRepetitions.js или https://github.com/mgechev/javascript-algorithms/blob/master/src/combinatorics/combinations.js

Answer (score 1):

На enSO был похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241174/javascript-generating-all-combinations-of-elements-in-a-single-array-in-pairs), можете там код посмотреть.

```js
const array = [51, 56, 58, 59, 61];
const results = [];

for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
  for (let j = i + 1; j < array.length; j++) {
    for (let k = j + 1; k < array.length; k++) {
      results.push([array[i], array[j], array[k]]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Как сделать без троих циклов